# Cassandra: Nodetool showing "?" in Owns

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I wonder why nodetools don't know the percentage of the ring handeld by my node...

I created this keyspace with

> CREATE KEYSPACE mykeyspace WITH replication = {'class': 'SimpleStrategy',
>   'replication_factor': '3'}  AND durable_writes = true;

[image: when nodetool status]

Someone has a clue?

Comment: How many nodes do you have in your cluster?  Is it just the one?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

okay got it. I have to specify a keyspace!

```
nodetool status mykeyspace
```

does the trick

Comment: Yup...should've just said that :P

Answer (score 10):

Do you get this at the bottom?

> Note: Non-system keyspaces don't have the same replication settings,
>   effective ownership information is meaningless

Do you have an opscenter / other keyspaces with different replication settings? In which case, ownership is "meaningless", and what you get is a ?

Comment: jep you are right...that's what it says! What is it trying to tell me?

Comment: Remember cassandra data is distributed across the nodes in the cluster. If all keyspaces have the same replication settings, then you can say node X own 25% of the data (or 30% or 10%...). However, if the replication settings across the keyspaces are different, there's no longer an "equal" distribution of data. A node may have data from one keyspace, or another with different replication parameters. As such, a figure like 25% doesn't mean anything - it might be coz replication's not working, or coz the node is "serving" little from a keyspace. Hence the message and the "?".

Answer (score 0):

These steps helped me. 
Kill the demon and restart Casansdra.

***nodetool status*** 
ERROR>>

Note: Non-system keyspaces don't have the same replication settings, effective ownership information is meaningless

Kill cansandra demon. 
 ***nodetool stopdemon*** 
systemctl status cassandra 
*systemctl start cassandra* 
nodetool status
    Good
[root@ip-10-0-1-10 centos]# *cqlsh localhost*